# Программа, которая находит элементы, сумма стоящих элементов строки до рассматриваемого элемента

Tags: c#, winforms, матрицы

Составить программу, которая в матрице D(m, n) находит все элементы, где сумма всех элементов строки, стоящих до рассматриваемого, больше суммы элементов столбца , стоящих до рассматриваемого. Сумму предшествующих элементов считать равной нулю, если элемент является первым в строке или столбце. Сформировать из найденных элементов массив. Вывести матрицу в виде матрицы, а под ней - элементы массива.

VS выдает 14 ошибок: Все имена dataGridView, numericUpDown, InitializeComponent не существуют в текущем контексте и Тип "Form1" уже определяет член "Form1" с такими же типами параметров.

Данный код пишу в Form1.Designer.cs (название по дефолту)

Помогите, пожалуйста, никак не могу понять что не так и что нужно добавить чтоб все работало..

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
 
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
 
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
 
        }
 
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView1.RowCount = int.Parse(numericUpDown1.Value.ToString());
 
            dataGridView1.ColumnCount= int.Parse(numericUpDown2.Value.ToString());
            
        }
 
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int n = dataGridView1.RowCount;
            int m = dataGridView1.ColumnCount;
            double[,] mas = new double[n,m];
 
            for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
                {
                    mas[i, j] = double.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString());
                        
                }
            int raz = 0;
            dataGridView2.RowCount = 1;
            dataGridView2.ColumnCount = 0;
 
            for(int i=0;i<=n;i++)
                for (int j = 0; j <= m; j++)
 
                {
                    double sum1=0;
                    double sum2=0;
 
                    if (i == 0)
                        sum1 = 0;
                    else
                        for (int k = 0; k < i ; k++)
                            sum1 += mas[i, k];
 
                    if (j == 0)
                        sum2 = 0;
                    else
                    for (int k = 0; k < j ; k++)
                        sum2 += mas[k, j];
 
 
                    if (sum1 > sum2)
                    {
                        
                        dataGridView2.ColumnCount++;
                        dataGridView2.Rows[0].Cells[raz].Value = mas[i, j];
                        raz++;
                    }
                }
 
 
 
 
 
        }
 
        private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Отправьте Form1.Dsiner.cs

Comment: Form1.Designer.cs нельзя изменять, это системный файл дизайнера формы. Птсать код гадо в Form1.cs.

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно вы испортили файл Form1.Designer.cs, теперь вам нужно удалить все элементы и заново их создавать.
Если не разбираетесь в коде Form1.Designer.cs - не нужно его редактировать, ибо всё что вы пишете там может быть удалено автоматически.
Пишите всё только в Form1.cs.